# Right way to pass a value from 'this' into 'then' function of promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to understand how to correctly use Promises in JS and I stumbled on following issue.

How to correctly/efficiently/in best way pass value into `then` function of Promise from `this` variable?

I am developing back-end using Node.js, MongoDB and Mongoose and have Calendar model, which I am extending with method `getFilteredIcal`. Right now I am storing `this` into temporary variable `calendar` so it would be accessible via closure from `then` function, but I don't like this approach and also think it is a wrong one.
See my problem in code attached.

```
var Calendar = new mongoose.Schema({
   url: String,
   userId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
});

Calendar.method.getFilteredIcal = function (respond) {
   var fetch = require('node-fetch');
   var icalCore = require('../tools/icalCore');
   var calendar = this; // <-- I don't like this
   fetch.Promise = require('bluebird');

   fetch(calendar.url)
    .then(icalCore.parseIcal)
    .then(parsedIcal => { return icalCore.filterIcal(parsedIcal, calendar._id) }) // <-- I need Calendar ID here 
    .then(icalCore.icalToString)
    .done(icalString => respond.text(icalString));
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are already using arrow functions, there is absolutely no need for this `calendar` variable that is closed over - arrow functions do resolve their `this` value lexically.

```
fetch(calendar.url)
.then(icalCore.parseIcal)
.then(parsedIcal => icalCore.filterIcal(parsedIcal, this._id))
//                                                  ^^^^
.then(icalCore.icalToString)
.done(icalString => respond.text(icalString));
```

Comment: Hmm I see and I have to admit that I forgot about this, but now when I think about it, since I am using bluebird and not native Promises, won't be this in context of of bluebird's Promise?
I have to try it out :-)

Comment: No, the arrow function is a language feature. It doesn't matter which promise implementation you use.

Comment: I see! I just test it and it worked! Thanks! :-)